# How to Override a function in NgOnit by another function?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have two functions `startTimer()` Which I am calling in the `NgOnit()`. I have also another function `stopTimer()`and I want it to work when the timer reaches`('00:00')`. I tried placing the `this.stoptimer()`function inside the `NgOnit` and the constructor but it overrides the 
`startimer()` function. If I put it outside the class I get an error `error TS1068: Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.`
I am thinking I either need to call the `stoptimer()` differently or I need to put it inside an if statement in the constructor but I do not know how to call the time property 
`time: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject('01:00');`

```
export class Pagename implements OnInit {
  sub: any;

  time: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject('01:00');

  timer: number;
  interval;

  state: 'start' | 'stop' = 'stop';

 ngOnInit() {

    this.startTimer(1);
}
 startTimer(duration: number) {
   this.state = 'start';
   clearInterval(this.interval);
   this.timer = duration * 60;
   this.interval = setInterval( () => {
     this.updateTimeValue();
   }, 1000);

 }
 stopTimer() {
   clearInterval(this.interval);
   this.time.next('00:00');
   this.state = 'stop';

 }

 updateTimeValue() {
   let minutes: any = this.timer / 60;
   let seconds: any = this.timer % 60;

   minutes = String('0' + Math.floor(minutes)).slice(-2);
   seconds = String('0' + Math.floor(seconds)).slice(-2);

   const text = minutes + ':' + seconds;
   this.time.next(text);


   --this.timer;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
updateTimeValue() {
    let minutes: any = this.timer / 60;
    let seconds: any = this.timer % 60;

    minutes = String('0' + Math.floor(minutes)).slice(-2);
    seconds = String('0' + Math.floor(seconds)).slice(-2);

    const text = minutes + ':' + seconds;
    this.time.next(text);

    --this.timer;
    // VVVVVVVVVVVV this is the change
    if (this.timer === 0) {
        this.stopTimer();
    }
}
```

Or, for short:

```
updateTimeValue() {
    let minutes: any = this.timer / 60;
    let seconds: any = this.timer % 60;

    minutes = String('0' + Math.floor(minutes)).slice(-2);
    seconds = String('0' + Math.floor(seconds)).slice(-2);

    const text = minutes + ':' + seconds;
    this.time.next(text);

    // decrement and check equality in the same line
    if (--this.timer === 0) {
        this.stopTimer();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already using a behavior subject in the "time" property, why not subscribe to the changes to this value, use the tap operator, then act on it. this way you can keep your functional areas separate.

```
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

this.time.pipe(
  tap( _time => {
    if (_time === '00:00') {
       this.stopTimer();
    }
  })
).subscribe();
```

You can put that in the constructor or call it from another method.